Cannot connect to AWS RDS after dockerizing my spring boot application
I'm tring to connect my spring boot application to AWS RDS. it can connect to rds successfully when I run it from the local machine, but if I run the docker image of my application, I encounter the following error:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

error message
It also happens after I run the application as a task on AWS ECS.
Can anyone help me figure out the problem? I have stucked on it for a whole night. Thanks!
I already set the inbound rule of my rds security group to all ipv4 ips, and tried adding my own ip, adding other security groups, setting SSL option in the connection uri parameter. No one works.
security group
